# How do I set the width of a textbox when editing a row in a GridView?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I've got a GridView that can be edited. My problem is that when I click **Edit**, the textbox is too small (the `File Name` column). It isn't large enough to display its contents, and it isn't as wide as the rest of the column.

How can I make that textbox wider?

---

Here's the ASP code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="FileGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="FileGridView_PageIndexChanging"
    CellPadding="1" CssClass="GridView"  GridLines="Horizontal"
    Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="GridView_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView_RowUpdating"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Length" HeaderText="Size" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Last Modified" ReadOnly="true" />
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridViewRow" />
    <EditRowStyle ForeColor="Black" CssClass="GridViewEditRow" />
    <SelectedRowStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="GridViewSelectedRow" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeader" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRow" />
</asp:GridView>
```

There's C# code behind this to update the data, and that works just fine. I hope the solution to this is in the ASP, but if the solution requires some C# code, that's OK with me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <controlstyle Width="200">
    </controlstyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can apply a *CSS* class to the control like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" 
    ControlStyle-CssClass="wide" />
```

And then set your `width` in your *StyleSheet*:

```
input.wide { width: 100px; }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the `ItemStyle-Width` for the column and the `ControlStyle-Width` for the control inside the column:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
    <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can covert the textbox/dropdownbox to a Templatefiled by going to Edit Filed Option. Then go to edit template, define width/height of box.